# How dose the factor $1/2$ in $E=\frac{1}{2} mv^2$ disappear in QM?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, schroedinger-equation

How dose the factor $1/2$ in $E=\frac{1}{2} mv^2$ disappear in QM?

The TDSE writes:
$$
H |\psi \rangle = i\hbar \frac{d}{dt}|\psi \rangle
$$
The momentum operator is defined as:
$$
\langle x|p|\psi \rangle=-i\hbar\frac{d\psi}{dx}
$$
Comparing the two operators, we can see that $p$ does have the dimension of Energy devided by velocity, which is that of momentum. Classically $E=\frac{1}{2} pv$. However, TDSE(which is related to energy of the system) doesn't have a factor of $1/2$.

Why the $1/2$ disappear in QM? I have seen several mathematical derivation, but I cannot find out exactly where this $1/2$ disappears.

Just explain why there is no 1/2 in TDSE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excellent question. The first equation encodes Einstein's relation $E= hf$ and the second encodes de Broglie's relation $p=h/\lambda$. Your paradox can be phrased as the surprise that $E/p = f\lambda$ which is an expression for a plane wave’s velocity $c$, but that in classical mechanics a free particle has energy $E=pv/2$, so that $c=\frac12v$, and this factor of one half is somewhat difficult to understand.

## Dispersive media

The key to understanding this involves understanding that $c$ is a speed for the internal structure of *pure plane* waves but what you actually have is the external structure of a wave *packet*, and while in the simplest case these both behave the same, they don't have to.

In dispersive mediums the speed of a plane wave depends on its wavelength, $c=c(\lambda)$. But we often prefer to instead express this as a function $\omega(k)=k~c(2\pi/k)$ so that we can express a plane wave as $f(x, t) =A~e^{i(k~x - \omega(k)~t)}.$

To form a Gaussian wavefunction in physical space is to form a complementary one in $k$-space as they are a Fourier conjugate pair and the Fourier transform of a Gaussian is another Gaussian, let's say centered on $k_0.$

And when you superimpose all of these plane waves and let them travel in space, the resulting wavefunction must be$$\Psi (x, t)=\int dk~e^{-s^2k^2/2}~e^{ikx-i\omega t}.$$

Expanding $\omega(k)$ around $k_0$ (assuming more spatial spread but a well-defined momentum) yields a Gaussian which actually travels at speed $\omega'(k_0)=[d\omega/dk]_{k=k_0}$. This derivative is the so-called **group velocity** and must be contrasted with $\omega/k,$ the **phase velocity**. Note that this isn't even a quantum result; it is a general statement of how waves work. A non-dispersive medium will have a linear dispersion relation, $c =\text{const.}$ hence $\omega = c~k$ hence $
d\omega/dk=c, $ too, but this is rarer. (It happens for relativistic free particles! Also for electrons in graphene, which is why you sometimes hear them called “relativistic” even though they travel much slower than light.)

## Sprinkling some quantum on it.

The dispersion relation is also nicely quantum: looking at the plane waves above,$p=\hbar k$ while $E=\hbar\omega$. So for a nonrelativistic particle  $E=p^2/(2m)$ so $\omega(k) = \hbar~ k^2/(2m).$

The phase velocity inside the packet is therefore $c= \omega(k)/k = \hbar~ k/(2m)$ while the group velocity of the packet is $v=d\omega/dk= \hbar~ k/m.$ So we see again that $c=v/2.$ The classical kinetic energy formula is a nice expression with quadratic dispersion and the wave theory has no problem with that.

Comment: Thank you for understanding and answering my poorly worded question. (Actually I have tried very hard to make the question clear)

Comment: How do you obtain the expression $\Psi(x,t)=\int ...$?

Comment: @MaJoad Suppose a linear differential equation in $x,t$ admits a finite basis of solutions $f_n(x, t)$, then the most general solution is the linear superposition $\Psi=\sum_n c_n~f_n(x,t)$ for coefficients $c_n$ and we can find the $c_n$ e.g. by finding $g_m(x)$ such that $\int dx~g_m(x)~f_n(x,0)=\delta_{mn}.$ If we instead have this continuous basis $f(k;x,t)$ then the proper generalization is a superposition $\Psi=\int dk~c(k)~f(k;x,t)$ and I have inferred that in this case I can use a Fourier transform of $\Psi(x,0)$ to find some Gaussian-ish expression for $c(k)$.

Answer (score 7):

$H=\frac{p^2}{2m}$ <- there it is.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't disappear. The classical kinetic energy $K = \frac{1}{2}mv^2$ is an algebraic equivalent of the form

$$ K = \frac{p^2}{2m}. $$

In quantum mechanics, the momentum operator is defined as

$$ \hat p = -i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x}. $$

Therefore the "kinetic energy operator" $\hat T$ can be found by plugging into our first classical equation (assuming non-relativistic velocities): $$\hat T = \frac{\hat p^2}{2m} = \frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}.$$
Here we are working in one dimension; more generally, $\hat T =\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2$.

Then you can derive the Hamiltonian $$\hat{\mathcal{H}} = \hat T + \hat V = \frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2 + V(\mathbf{r}). $$

Note the coefficient of the $\nabla$ operator:
$$ \frac{1}{2}\frac{\hbar^2}{m}.$$
The factor of 1/2 was never lost, it was carried by the fact that $T = \frac{1}{2}\frac{p^2}{m}.$ So when we say we have the time-independent $\mathcal{H}\Psi = E\Psi$ or -depdendent $\mathcal{H}\Psi = i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Psi$ Schrödinger equations, the factor of 1/2 is buried in the Hamiltonian $\mathcal{H}$.

Comment: But why there is no 1/2 in TDSE?

Comment: @MaJoad See my edited response. There is always a 1/2 in the TDSE, it's just inside the Hamiltonian operator. Please consider accepting this answer if it is satisfactory; otherwise, I'm happy to continue discussion.